# Whisper model slows down as concurrency increases

Tags: python, tensorflow, concurrency, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently facing an issue with the performance of my AI audio analytics system, which utilizes the Whisper model ("medium"). Here are the details of the problem:

My GPU has 16GB of RAM, and each whisper instance requires 5GB. I'm using celery, launching a task that load a model and loop through audios.

- When I launch the analytics for 1000 audio files with a concurrency setting of 1, it takes 18 minutes.
- Surprisingly, when I increase the concurrency to 2, the time taken is greater, at 24 minutes.
- 24 minutes also for concurrency at 3

```py
@celery.task(name="whisper")
def whisper(self, datas: object) :
    model = whisper.load_model("medium")
    allResults = []
    for audio in data:
        res = model.transcribe(audio)
        allResults.append(res)
    del model
    return allResults
```

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    celery.send_task("whisper", args=[[333 audios...]], kwargs={})
    celery.send_task("whisper", args=[[333 audios...]], kwargs={})
    celery.send_task("whisper", args=[[333 audios...]], kwargs={})
```

I expected a decrease in processing time with increased concurrency, but it seems that the GPU is not handling concurrency as efficiently as anticipated. Could this be causing each process to slow down?

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to optimize the performance and make better use of the GPU resources.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: I've edited my post

Comment: Please edit the title to correct Whiser to Whisper.

Comment: Interesting thing, on an other computer with a 2080Ti GPU, concurrency improve the performance related to the GPU :
2000 seconds with concurrency 2, 2400 seconds with concurrency 1
The time is worse than 4060Ti, but concurrency improves the performance on the dedicated GPU